# create date range array from a list of dates using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, date

What is the best way to create an array of hashes with date ranges from a list of dates. For example: If I have a list of dates in an array as below:

`['12/11/2014','13/11/2014','14/11/2014','24/11/2014','25/11/2014','26/11/2014','27/11/2014','28/11/2014','29/11/2014','04/12/2014','05/12/2014','06/12/2014','07/12/2014','24/12/2014','25/12/2014','26/12/2014', '28/12/2014', '30/12/2014']`

I am trying to get array of date ranges hashes something like below:

`[{:from => '12/11/2014', :to => '14/11/2014'}, {:from => '24/11/2014', :to => '29/11/2014'}, {:from => '04/12/2014', :to => '07/12/2014'}, {:from => '24/12/2014', :to => '26/12/1014'}, {:from => '28/12/2014', :to => '28/12/2014'}, {:from => '30/12/2014', :to => '30/12/2014'}]`

Anything available in Ruby to generate something like this ? Thanks.

Comment: what pattern you follow to get `from` and `to` date from the array?

Answer (score 3):

Enumerable has the `slice_before` method which can do what you want, with the addition of some added code. This is from [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

> If the block needs to maintain state over multiple elements, local variables can be used. For example, three or more consecutive increasing numbers can be squashed as follows:

```
a = [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
prev = a[0]
p a.slice_before { |e|
  prev, prev2 = e, prev
  prev2 + 1 != e
}.map { |es|
  es.length <= 2 ? es.join(",") : "#{es.first}-#{es.last}"
}.join(",")
#=> "0,2-4,6,7,9"
```

Obviously it isn't the complete answer, but I am not at my computer which has code that will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

array = ['12/11/2014','13/11/2014','14/11/2014','24/11/2014','25/11/2014','26/11/2014','27/11/2014','28/11/2014','29/11/2014','04/12/2014','05/12/2014','06/12/2014','07/12/2014','24/12/2014','25/12/2014','26/12/2014', '28/12/2014', '30/12/2014']

dates = array.map { |datestr| [datestr, Date.parse(datestr)] }
prev = nil
ranges = dates.slice_before { |datestr, date|
  ((prev ? date - prev : 1) != 1).tap { prev = date }
}.map { |dates|
  { from: dates[0][0], to: dates[-1][0] }
}
```

It is a bit more complicated than it needs to be because you're using date strings instead of dates. Also, it might be better to use an array of `Range` objects than of hashes:

```
dates = array.map(&Date.method(:parse))
prev = nil
pp dates.slice_before { |date|
  ((prev ? date - prev : 1) != 1).tap { prev = date }
}.map { |dates| dates[0]..dates[-1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use an enumerator. Suppose you have an array:

```
a = %w[a b d e f i k l m n o t]
  #=> ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "i", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "t"]
```

then

```
arr = [[a.first]]
enum = a[1..-1].to_enum
loop do
  e = enum.next
  last = arr.last
  if last.last.succ == e
    last << e
  else
    arr << [e]
  end
end
arr
  #=> [["a", "b"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["i"], ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o"], ["t"]]
```

[Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises a `StopIteraration` exception when an attempt is made to go beyond the last element of the enumerator `enum`. [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

In your application, `a` will be a sorted array of `Date` objects. You can use [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and the class method [Date::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) to convert your strings to `Date` objects (and sort if necessary).  Note that this works with any collection of objects that respond to `succ`, `Date` objects being one ([Date#succ](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-succ)).